# There was a something wrong with facebook login with different accounts?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

Firstly I want to say I search more than 1 week about this but I ve not found the solution what I need.

**My simple target :** I want to login facebook with my android app.

**What I did :** I found many sample to login facebook and I tried all of them.(I give codes which belongs to one of them) I create developer facebook account. And I add platform for android. It gives me App ID and secret. And I generate key hash in two methods(I have same the key hash for two of them) :

1.

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

2.

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.you.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
        Log.e("hash key", something);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

And I have the key hash like this :

```
6R5************hZZbeBU=
```

the last char is '=' I write all of chars to the facebook app settings,
And I write my APP_ID to my android project.

**What is the problem :** The problem which I see on the all of my projects , is the same. 
problem is I connect facebook with my account which the creator of the APP_ID .
**I mean When I login with my account I connect yes I also post,see my friends , upload photo ,,,**
but when I login to my app with **different account** I can t login.open just empty white page like this:
[image]

Actually I do not understand this and the more interesting thing is , when I download different android facebook projects I try them. And sure , I **copy my app_id**  and again I connect facebook but different accounts I did not success to connect facebook.

What is the problem ? Should I do something on Facebook side like give permission or something else...

thanks,,,

Comment: is your facebook app is live or in sandbox mode? i doubt its in sandbox!

Comment: I guess it is sandbox actually I do not know sandbox what it is and how can I make it go on live.

Comment: go to facebook developer page where you have created the app and make it live!

Comment: Thanks for answer , I do not know how can it but I can search it on google

Comment: @MuhammadBabar thanks for answer please make an answer so I can tick it true thanks it works , thank you so much...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your **Facebook App** *Live* from *Sandbox* mode.